# Sklearn: is it possible to specify null or NaN values for unknown categories in OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I am working with a dataset of mixed categorical and numeric variables. There is lots of missing data and as such, I am hoping to do some imputation through classifiers. I am currently using `fast_knn` from `impyute.imputation.cs`. `fast_knn` is an easy to use function that fills in missing values with a kNN model.

My hope is to pass a `numpy` array into `fast_knn` that contains one hot encodings for the categorical variables, with `np.nan` in place for the values that are missing, mixed with the data from numeric attributes (also with `np.nan` in place for values that are missing).

The difficulty is making sure the missing values are apparent after converting categorical data to one hot encodings. **How can I convert categorical data to one hot encodings such that missing values result in `np.nan` (as opposed to a one hot encoding)?** I have been struggling with this for some time embarrassingly — I was under the impression that `OneHotEncoder` from `scikit` places 0-filled arrays for missing values, but I don't believe this is correct.

I would like to use a throwaway example. Suppose I had a dataset with three features, two categorical and one numeric. Here is an example of the final structure I would like. The first two features are categorical and the third is numeric:

```
#np.nan is in place for any missing value. 

[
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], np.nan],
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], np.nan] #Suppose this category has 8 possible values the attribute can take on. 
[1, 3, np.nan, 3, 5]
]
```

`fast_knn` would impute wherever there is `np.nan`.

I hope my question is clear. Keep in mind that the categorical subset is quite large — 145000 rows x 5 columns. It would be good to not do something computationally expensive. I am hoping for a technique besides designating missing values as another kind of value a categorical attribute can take on and then iterating through the one hot encodings to change it back to `np.nan`.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the reason for imputing missing values for unknown categories ?

Comment: @Miguel Trejo Thank you for such a great answer. By imputing missing values, I can have a complete dataset — which will allow me to do the prediction.

It looks like I have encountered another error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` I think this error is arising because the dataset contains a mix of one hot encodings and numerical values (for the numeric data). I am looking to stay clear of ordinal or label encoding to avoid imposing unneeded directionality. I have made the one hot encodings and will do a dimensionality reduction through PCA to keep everything neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. One Hot Encoder (np.nan for unknown values not supported)

If you want to go with the one hot encoding approach, `OneHotEncoder` does indeed set a zero array for unknown values, consider for example

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))

enc.fit(s.values.reshape(-1, 1))

t = enc.transform(np.array(['a', 'c', 'Other', 'b', 'Another']).reshape(-1, 1))
t
>>>
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

the unknown categories `Other` and `Another` are zero arrays. To replace all zero arrays in `t`

```
zero_cond = (t == 0).all(axis=1)
t[zero_cond] = np.nan
t
>>> 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
```

which you can now pass to the imputer.

### 2. Ordinal Encoder (unknown values can be set to np.nan)

Another option to handle your categorical variables that sets `Nan` for unknown variables is [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) (since scikit-learn version 0.24)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=np.nan)

enc.fit(s.values.reshape(-1, 1))

enc.transform(np.array(['a', 'c', 'Other', 'b', 'Another']).reshape(-1, 1))
>>>
array([[ 0.],
       [ 2.],
       [nan],
       [ 1.],
       [nan]])
```